# How do I save article ids in Javascript or HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-ui

I have a list of links in the web-page and users can click and comment on them. I load the links via JSON and each link is uniquely identified by an id.

My question is how do I know which link has been clicked? Even though I have an id, where do I store it(If Javascript object, how?)? I guess I cannot have it as a tag attribute because users may change it.

Comment: I tried setting the id to the div of the link, but I fear user may change it.

Comment: paste html or jquery code u tried please

Comment: Give us a jsFiddle with the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to create a link to a page with a specific ID, without actually displaying the ID? If this is the case, I think you'll face difficulties doing that in a simple way, as javascript client-side and the user will most likely be able to alter the id anyway. I'd recommend keeping the id in the link (`<a href="url.com/post/42>`, for example) and rather, when the page is loaded, in some way or another, check if the provided URL is actually a valid, existing ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attributes which stays hidden from end user.

Eg: `<a id="link1" data-myuniqueid="XXXXX"> Link1 </a>`

Using Javascript, you can access/modify data values

```
var ele = document.getElementById("link1");
var uid = ele.getAttribute('data-myuniqueid'); // For compatibility
var uid = ele.dataset.myuniqueid;  // HTML5 way - does not work in old browsers
```

if you need more explaination for using custom data attributes, [this](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) might help.

**-- EDIT --**

I guess above answer will not be sufficient to address your problem. You can store objects in data attributes or try something like this -

```
var ele = document.getElementById("link1");
ele.myuniqueid = "XXXXXX"
```

myuniqueid will not be visible to user even in source.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a tag attribute - anything that is send to the browsers, users can change. If a user wants to change the id - let him do it. He can also click on the article that he wants to comment on and do that as well.

Comment: The problem with users changing it is that I may go and update comment for a different link.

Comment: Then you have a security problem that wouldn't be solved by obfuscating the id storage. You have to identify that a user has created the comment. For example to force him to register in order to comment on articles, and them to check if the current logged in user is the owner of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sessionStorage in HTML5 suppoerted by all the browsers. It can also retain if the page gets reloaded

```
//for setting value 
sessionStorage.LinkClicked= "4";

//to get the value
var temp = sessionStorage.LinkClicked;
```

Here is the link for more info http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Hope, it may help you. Have anice day. :)

Comment: The local storage is not supported in older browsers, so kind of a problem.

Comment: ya that's a issue. :|

Answer (score 0):

for storing data on the client side.
if your not fussy about cross browser compadablility, you could go with a html5 soultion such as local storage.

http://html5sql.com/

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

if your looking to get the id from a element and your using jQuery you can uses this in your event handler

```
$().attr('id');
```